# Reversing the item order of a list in prolog

Tags: list, prolog, reverse

Can somebody explain to me the following code:

```
t(L, NL) :-
    t(L, [], NL).
t([], L, L). 
t([H|T], A, NL) :-
    t(T, [H|A], NL).
```

I would have implemented it completely differently:

```
s([], []). 
s([H|T], NL) :-
    s(T, NT),
    append(NT, [H], NL).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make use of an accumulator, the second parameter. Intitially this is set to the empty list, indeed:

```
t(L, NL) :-
    t(L, [], NL).  % ← empty list
```

then we each time perform pattern matching on the first parameter. If it is empty, we return the accumulator as reversed list:

```
t([], L, L).  % ← list empty? Unify the accumulator L with the result (third parameter)
```

If the list is not empty, we will perform unification with `[H|T]`, so `H` is the first list, and `T` the list of remaining elements, and we *prepend* the accumulator with `H`:

```
t([H|T], A, NL) :-
    t(T, [H|A], NL).  % ← prepend H to the accumutor.
```

If we thus have a list `[1,4,2,5]` we will each time prepend the accumulator with the head of the list and recurse on the tail, so it looks like:

```
 list (L)  | accumulator (A)
-----------------------------
 [1,4,2,5] |              []
 [4,2,5]   |             [1]
 [2,5]     |           [4,1]
 [5]       |         [2,4,1]
 []        |       [5,2,4,1]
```

so when the we eventually call the `t/3` predicate with `L` empty, the accumulator contains the list in reverse.

The advantage of doing this is that it is efficient: prepending takes *O(1)* time, just as unification with `[H|T]` does, so this means we reverse in *O(n)* time.

`append/3` takes linear time in the length of the first parameter, so by using `append/3` here, you obtain the reverse in *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* time.